# Email going to spam in gmail because SPF records fail - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, email, spf

I have an issue with the email going to spam on one of my WordPress websites.  I am testing a gmail account. I am not sure why the email is received from the host see.seekmomentum.com and not the domain of the account rodriguez-music.com.

This is the SPF record that is setup:

"v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:198.57.217.77 +a:see.seekmomentum.com +include:see.seekmomentum.com ~all"

Here is the email header:

```
Delivered-To: adam@seekmomentum.com
Received: by 10.36.78.75 with SMTP id r72csp813793ita;
Thu, 12 Feb 2015 18:43:53 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.67.8.98 with SMTP id dj2mr11270446pad.134.1423795433239;
Thu, 12 Feb 2015 18:43:53 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <rodrigue@see.seekmomentum.com>
Received: from see.seekmomentum.com (see.seekmomentum.com. [198.57.217.77])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id c2si1020944pas.234.2015.02.12.18.43.52
    for <adam@seekmomentum.com>
    (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
    Thu, 12 Feb 2015 18:43:53 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: none (google.com: rodrigue@see.seekmomentum.com does not designate permitted sender hosts) client-ip=198.57.217.77;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
spf=none (google.com: rodrigue@see.seekmomentum.com does not designate permitted sender hosts) smtp.mail=rodrigue@see.seekmomentum.com
Received: from rodrigue by see.seekmomentum.com with local (Exim 4.82)
(envelope-from <rodrigue@see.seekmomentum.com>)
id 1YM6ES-0008GV-4P
for adam@seekmomentum.com; Thu, 12 Feb 2015 21:43:52 -0500
To: adam@seekmomentum.com
Subject: WP Mail SMTP: Test mail to adam@seekmomentum.com
Date: Fri, 13 Feb 2015 02:43:52 +0000
From: Rodriguez Music <sales@rodriguez-music.com>
Message-ID: <4bb4be1574fad992ef467c20edccc40e@www.rodriguez-music.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - see.seekmomentum.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - seekmomentum.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [504 500] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - see.seekmomentum.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: see.seekmomentum.com: authenticated_id:     rodrigue/from_h
X-Source: /usr/bin/php
X-Source-Args: /usr/bin/php /home/rodrigue/public_html/wp-admin/options-    general.php 
X-Source-Dir: rodriguez-music.com:/public_html/wp-admin

This is a test email generated by the WP Mail SMTP WordPress plugin.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are actually several problems here:

1. For whatever reason, the SMTP server is setting the Return-Path domain to see.seekmomentum.com .  You need to figure out why that's happening.  How are you sending this email?
2. The SPF record for rodriguez-music.com is broken.  You are including see.seekmomentum.com, which has no SPF record.

To fix your immediate problem, you could simply add an SPF record to see.seekmomentum.com with the IP address in question.  But you should understand why the Return-Path domain is not what you expect, especially if you're planning to add DMARC (which you should).